# Is there a way to make c++ console text larger?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, console

I'm making a random number generator, the program will create several random numbers and then choose from those random numbers and then displays that number in the window.

I was wondering if there was a way to make that specific piece of text bigger?
I don't want to change the size of all of the text in the window as I have writing in the window that i don't want to change the size of

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 6):

No, but you can make it bold, change the font color, or the background color for the specific text.  If all you want is to make that specific piece of text stand out, I'd go with colorizing it.

As for how to do that... It's platform dependent.  What platform are you on?  Windows?  Linux?  What shell?

Take a look at the [Windows Console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4).  That should have what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Console text doesn't allow for the rich formatting you are referring to.  You would have to move to a graphical output to render the size differences.

Comment: I feared as much  :/  I don't have much knownledge to go graphical with c++, can only do console stuff so far

Answer (score 3):

Generally, programs can't control the size of the text in the terminal.  You may be able to change the color of a specific part of the text, though.  Search for terminal escape sequences for information on how to do that on various terminals.  Some terminals also handle bold, italics, and underlining.

Answer (score 2):

No, but instead you can change colors of text and text's background. Will this be a good solution for your problem? There are a lot of specific examples available in the internet.

Answer (score 2):

A possible console mode solution could involve [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org). You can tweak the output to write in many different fonts.

The output is larger, but no guarantee that it's suitable for your application.

Comment: Hmm, interesting solution, but implementing a library is far more involved than learning how to program a library.  Still, +1 for a great resource.

Comment: There's no need to implement anything. Simply `system("figlet hello");` is all that is really needed.

Comment: So i should include this library and i could invoke the function to output the number in the larger asci art style font using the system function?

Comment: I don't think there is a library for FIGlet. It's just an executable, `figlet.exe` (somewhere you should be able to find one built for Windows). When you run it with text on the command line, it writes that text to standard output in a larger font. There are many command line options to control its behaviour. If you need even more control over the output, use `popen()` to read its output into your program and do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 0):

open your console app, go to system menu of console window (left top corner, right click), font tab, choose what you wish. next time you open this (!) console app the font will be as you selected, other console windows are not affected

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click the top bar of the window

   [image: select top bar]
2. Click Properties
3. Click Font and select your font size

[image: select font size]

This isn't through the code but it will help for your pc.